# Multiple the sum of digit of a number

Tags: java

I am having a hard time figuring out the solution to this problem. I need to write a program that gets an input n (via scanner), then goes with a for loop till that input number, checks if the numbers are divisible by 13 and then multiplies the digits of each number.

So for an example, if the input number is 40, the divisible numbers by 13 would be 13, 26, 39

```
1+3 = 4,
2+6 = 8,
3+9 = 12
```

so that's 4*8*12 = 384.

My current code, but I'm stuck here. I probably didn't do it right, too:

```
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

int num = myScanner.nextInt();
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 30; i = i + 1) {
    if (i % 13 == 0) {
        while (i > 0) {
            int add = i % 10;
            sum = sum + add;
            i = i / 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're computing the sum of the digits, not the product. Also, you're loop is going to 30, not to `num`. (There's also no reason to start the loop at 0 instead of 1.) Finally, you shouldn't be changing `i` inside the loop itself; that will screw up the iteration logic. Use an auxiliary variable. Something like this (untested) should work:

```
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

int num = myScanner.nextInt();
int prod = 1;

for (int i = 1; i < num; i++) {
    if (i % 13 == 0) {
        int j = i,
            sumOfDigits = 0;
        while (j > 0) {
            int digit = j % 10;
            sumOfDigits += digit;
            j /= 10;
        }
        prod *= sumOfDigits;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your whole code is messy. You need to work more on loops and variable assignments and scopes.
Given below is the correct code.

```
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num = myScanner.nextInt();

    int mul = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < num; i = i + 1) {
        if (i % 13 == 0) {
            int sum = 0;
            int number = i; // = some int

            while (number > 0) {
                sum = sum + (number % 10);
                number = number / 10;
            }
            mul = mul * sum;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(mul);
    myScanner.close();
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site, not a homework writing service.  Please do not give users reason to believe otherwise.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do it, change the number that are divisible to char array, then add and multiply.

```
   Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    int prod = 1;



    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++) {
        if (i % 13 == 0) {

            String number = String.valueOf(i);
            char[] digits1 = number.toCharArray();

            int sum = 0;

            for (char ii:digits1) {

                sum = Character.getNumericValue(ii) + sum;

            }
            prod = prod*sum;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(prod);
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site, not a homework writing service.  Please do not give users reason to believe otherwise.  Thank you.

Comment: @JoeC there's clear  "evidence that effort has been made" in the original post.

Comment: @Alvin I'm sorry for you being downvoted for helping me out. Clearly that effort has been made, he didn't even care to read the post itself, just went on a rampage of downvoting my questions across the site. Sorry!

Comment: @Itored I read the post, and I did not spot a question.  All I saw was "here's the assignment, here's some code."  Nothing to tell us what issue you're facing with this code, or what effort you've put in to debug it yourself.  Just saying "here's some broken code, fix it" is not good enough here.